# grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll library not unloaded when application domain is unloaded

Tags: c#, grpc, appdomain

I am using some Google Cloud services, some of which rely on GRPC. I am using these services in a separate C# application domain to enable me to unload, update and reload the module where this functionality is provided.

My issue is that, while I can successfully unload the application domain the grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll library remains loaded so I cannot delete that directory which contains the files.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to get the application domain to also unload this DLL so I can properly upgrade my application in place?

**Update:**  Here is a github with a minimal solution that shows the issue.

https://github.com/jamesrusso/grpcappdomainunloaderror

Comment: I would guess that assembly is also gets loaded into the primary AppDomain to deserialize exceptions and/or other stuff passed between app domains. If that’s the case, there’s probably not much you can do about it without changing the app logic to prevent such objects from crossing domain boundaries.

Comment: Nothing is passed between the app domains. Just a simple start/stop command. The main application (the application which creates and loads the app domain) also does use google services. So, that dll is certainly loaded in the main application (but from a different directory). The "plugin" directory should be completely self contained. I had thought that maybe I was not shutting down a service properly, but I haven't been able to chase that down yet.

Comment: Although nothing is explicitly passed between app domains, there’s still could be some types passed implicitly. Exceptions thrown in the secondary domain and handled/logged in the primary one is one example. I’d try adding AssemlyResolve and AssemblyLoad event handlers for the main AppDomain to see what’s happening and confirm or rule out such possibilities.

Comment: Good points about the exceptions. I had not thought about that. Something, I think just having a separate process would be easier than a separate app domain. 

I think I have it tracked done to something to do with Google Cloud Logging and grpc. If I disable the setup of the google cloud logging, once the domain is unloaded I am able delete the directory without issue.

Comment: Running a separate process can indeed be easier when you don’t have a full control over the behavior of 3rd-party libraries, especially if there’s no interactions between the main program and the plugin besides starting/stopping it.

Comment: The grpc_csharp_ext.x86.dll library is not managed, so I suspect that the managed code is somehow loading it. I still cannot figure it out and am about to give up on the dream of having a separate app domain and just have the service spawn another process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208840/discussion-between-jr-and-alex-skalozub).